# Internet disconnects after inserting a USB device

Tags: usb, ethernet, connection

I have 3 PCs connecter via LAN cable to my ethernet router. But when I plug in a usb device on the PC that I have on my room, the other 2 PCs disconect from the internet.This happens when the PC that causes disconection is offline.If I turn it to on line then the other PCs connect.But I don't want to have it online all the time.

This problem is very annoying because when I put a usb storage disk or a usb tv tuner on my pc I have always to disconnect it's LAN cable from the router in order to keep the internet connection to the other 2

The Router is seted on it's default setting.I upgraded the firmware but nothing happened.I also upgraded the LAN drivers but also nothing happened

Do you have any ideas how to fix my problem?

The 2 other PCs lose internet connection whenever I insert a usb stick or a usb TV tuner on the first PC (while the first is offline). If I enable the internet connection by windows to the first PC only then, the other two connect to the Internet.  The router doesn't have any USB ports at all.

I share nothing between all computers nor printers or common used devices etc. The router is setup using it's default ISP settings. I never made any changes to this router or made any network modifications. All 3 PCs are connected directly through their LAN cables to the router

Comment: Do you share the internet connection through your PC? If so is it via a 3G modem or similar?

Comment: This seems to be a hardware problem on the PC with the USB. What sort of PC is it? What OS? Does it happen on all its USB ports? Does it happen with separately powered devices? You may be able to work round it with a powered USB hub.

Comment: @burgi - The questioner says he is connected by a LAN cable to an Ethernet router.

Comment: No, each connection is separated.There is no home network.Each PC connects by itself through the it's LAN cable which is connected to the router. I' ve never used 3G. The OS are  Win XP 32bit (service pack 3) on the two and Win 7 32 bit on the other. The PC that causes the problem has XP. Yes it happens on all ports.Never used separately powered devices.USB stick and USB tunet get electricity from USB port.It didn't try with a USB hub.I don't think that this will fix the problem.I don't think there is a difference if you use a hub or connect directly to the USB

Comment: @AFH the router could have been just used as a switch.

Comment: @Anastasia - The point is not the data connection, but the power: a powered hub will allow USB devices to draw power from the hub instead of from the PC. From the symptoms you describe, the most likely explanation is a power supply problem, though other causes are possible.

Comment: I'm sorry, this is mostly a clarification post, I am not able to comment as I am a new user here. Do the other 2 computers lose the LAN as well or just the internet? Could you do an ipconfig/all before and after USB connection for all 3 of these computers?

Comment: *part 2 of @Cand3r's converted comment:* "Does the router have a USB port on it? Do you share printers/drives/anything from the computer that you are having USB problems with? There are documented flaws with NetUSB/routers with USB ports. http://www.computerworld.com/article/2936338/networking/what-most-people-dont-know-about-the-netusb-router-flaw-part-1.html

If the router does have a USB port, check in the settings and see if has netUSB, turn it off if you can."